# Oracle SQL RTRIM and replacing CHR 13,10,160,9 still leaving space at the end

Tags: sql, oracle

The original query returned `result`.

It had what looks like two spaces after the period.

I tried RTRIM and it removes ONE of the spaces `result`.

I then tried to replace the CHR characters with no luck.

```sql
rtrim(replace(COLUMN,CHR(13)||CHR(10)||CHR(160)||CHR(9),''))  as FORMATTED_COLUMN
```

What other things can I try?

Comment: It is best to find out first what characters really are there. For that, do this: `select dump(COLUMN) from YOUR_TABLE where ...` with the "where" clause used to select just the row you need to look at. DUMP shows you the bytes saved in that column; space is 32, linefeed is 10, etc. Who knows what else you may find - nonbreaking space? Some other weird white-space character or characters?

Comment: From duplicate, use regex: `regexp_replace(myColumn, '[[:space:]]+$', '')`

Answer (score 0):

To make your current approach work, you would have to use `REGEXP_REPLACE` with an alternation:

```sql
REGEXP_REPLACE(COLUMN, '[' || CHR(13) || '|' || CHR(10) || '|' || CHR(160) || '|' || CHR(9) || ']+$', '')
```

If you wanted to use plain `REPLACE`, then you would have to chain function calls:

```sql
RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(COLUMN, CHR(13), ''), CHR(10), ''), CHR(160), ''), CHR(9), ''))
```

But then the replacements would happen *everywhere*, and not just at the end of the string.

Comment: Simplest is to use RTRIM directly (not in the way the OP was using).